# WTForms- RadioField allow no choice selection

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms

Is there a way to not require the user to select a choice in RadioField? Even with no validators, it always returns "Not a valid choice"

Comment: have you tried the Optional validator?

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer:

```
from wtforms.validators import Optional

class newform(Form):
    wellbeing=RadioField('How are you feeling?',choices=[('good','good'),('bad','bad'), validators=[Optional()]
```

thanks to attack68 for the suggestion.